# check tls version without using third party

Tags: ssl, sharepoint, browser

How to check TLS version of a browser without using the third party from a SharePoint solution file(login page)? I don't want to use "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check?callback=parseTLSinfo" since I am not allowed to use a third party service.I am using sharepoint server 2016 on premise.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: do you want to know what TLS version is supported by the browser (depends on browser and maybe OS) or do you want to know which TLS version is used when accessing a specific site (depends on both browser/OS and server)? In any case: both can be found out if you look at the traffic with Wireshark.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich   I want to know which TLS version is used for accessing a specific site.My apologies for not mentioning it before. I have a login page(solution file .aspx in SharePoint 2016 onprem)  when login button is clicked and if the tls version is not matching i need a pop up. I searched in the internet and got answers before finding the TLS version using a third party or ActiveX object. only.

Comment: *"if the tls version is not matching i need a pop up"* - you don't have access to the information from inside the browser. You might have access to these information at the server, depending on the server and framework (i.e. [SSL_PROTOCOL variable in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#page-header)) and can then reply with the appropriate answer.